# react useState and useEffect quickie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert an older style react class to a newer function that uses useState and useEffect instead of this.setState and componentDidMount but can't get it to quite work - can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong - finding hooks quite confusing - thanks

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const App = function() {
  function  getWeather(){
      fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=6e93b3d15872f914c6929fed9ea71e9a')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data
        })
  
  }
  const[weatherData,setData] = useState(getWeather())

  useEffect(()=>{
    setData(getWeather)
  },[])
  
    
    return(<div>
    
    {weatherData.main.temp}
    
    </div>)
  
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const App = function() {
  function  getWeather(){
      fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=6e93b3d15872f914c6929fed9ea71e9a')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            setData(data);
        })
  
  }
  const[weatherData,setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    getWeather();
  },[])
  
    
    return(<div>
    
    {weatherData.main?weatherData.main.temp:""}
    
    </div>)
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks I tried that but get the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'weatherData.main.temp')

Comment: Sorry. I edited my answer. Please try again.

Comment: thank you so much but could you explain what this line is doing with the question mark and quotes?
{weatherData.main?weatherData.main.temp:""}

Comment: If weatherData.main is not null, we can display weatherData.main.temp, but weatherData.main is null we can't evaluate the weatherData.main.temp.

Comment: So I added that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230942/discussion-between-etsuko-susui-and-ron-southin).

Comment: I can't post comments in the chat - maybe because I'm on safari?